# What's a good (preferably standard) was to restore iptables config in ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I never quite got why this isn't some built in setup, although maybe it is and stuff changes so quickly I just missed it.
I can use iptables-save to generate something I can feed into iptables-restore, but what I was wondering is if there was a standard place to put it so that it gets picked up on boot without me having to add something to rc.local or the ever changing init/event.d scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ubuntu community help site it seems that Ubuntu has no default method to save rules, but the site suggests two ways:

- pre-up and post-down statements in /etc/network/interfaces
- scripts in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d and ../if-post-down.d

See [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) for details.

Personally I prefer to use Shorewall and Shorewall6 to simplify iptables configuration, which restores iptables rules at startup automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pretty common for people to use a front-end to iptables like [firehol](http://firehol.sourceforge.net/), shorewall, etc, or many others instead of manipulating the tables themselves.  Most of these packages setup init scripts to install the rules at boot time for you, and you place your rules in a configuration file appropriate to that tool.

My preference is firehol, I really like the simplified syntax that I get.  You don't have to sacrifice flexibility, you can create far more complex rules when you need them.  It creates lots of chains to make the rule processing a lot more efficient then you typically see in rules sets entered by hand.

Comment: Shorewall has a nice feature where you can save a default configuration; if you try to apply a new config that fails for some reason, it will re-apply the saved configuration.

Comment: @Tim Howland, with firehol if you use `firehol try` it too will attempt to install a new config and revert to the previous running config if there are any failures.