# iptables configuration under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm following a [tutorial on setting up a dns-tunnel](http://thomer.com/howtos/nstx.html).

I've run into the following instruction:

> Now you need to enable forwarding on this server. I use iptables to implement masquerading. There are many HOWTOs about this (a simple one, for example). On Debian, the configuration file for iptables is in /var/lib/iptables/active. The relevant bit is:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:1596]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:76]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Restart iptables:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

The problem is that I don't have any `/var/lib/iptables/active`. (I'm on ubuntu.)

How can I accomplish this? I suspect that I should just interact with the `iptables` command somehow but I have no clue what to write. Best would probably be if I could put the commands in a script somehow I suppose.

(A side-note. If I execute a few `iptables`-commands it wont be there for ever, right? The rules will be discarded on reboot?)

Comment: While you can directly manipulate firewall rules, I strongly suggest you consider using a front-end script like firehol.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/397/how-to-setup-simple-firewall-on-ubuntu and http://serverfault.com/questions/126795/whats-a-good-preferably-standard-was-to-restore-iptables-config-in-ubuntu-9-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE
```

If you want it to be applied everytime the system boots the easiest way will be to put in the file `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` line.

Best of luck,
João Miguel Neves

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, there's no /var/lib/iptables/active on my debian system, so i'm guessing this guide/howto is out of date a little bit.

i'm not even really sure what to make of:

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:1596]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:76]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]

i'm guessing it's either the default rules for the chains or specifying you should allow ports 6 to 1596, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it simpler to install Shorewall and let it manage the iptables for you.  It is packaged for Debian and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package that contains a system service to restore

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

put rules in /etc/iptables/rules.

one way to do this is:

```
sudo bash -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules"
```